# Risk of exposing an ID of entry in DRF framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm building an API and I've started using the GenericAPIViews. In this example

```
class InsertActivityChange(UpdateAPIView):
    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []
    serializer_class = ActivitiesSerializer
    lookup_field = 'id'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Activities.objects.filter(id=self.kwargs['id'])
        
    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

`path('insertactivitychange/<int:id>', views.InsertActivityChange.as_view(), name='insertactivitychange'),`

I've used a generic class to do updates for an object. My concern is if I'm risking much by allowing the ID to be directly inputted after the URL. Obviously, I'd further mitigate the risk by properly configuring the authentication and permission class, so is the ID of the entry even a security risk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're worried about access, remember to add permissions and filters. If you're focused on security and hiding resources, make sure they will 404 instead of 401 or 403. Have a look at [DRF filtering](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/) section and in serializers use `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` `queryset` where you filter based on `user`.

If you're worried about exposing `pk`s, just use UUIDs. It will still be visible but a human can't predict what the next id is.

So even if 3rd party knows the id of a resource, it should return 404 if you want to hide a resource. That way you expose a meaningless value to the attacker.

Comment: I'll mark this as a solution. I've already implemented custom permissions to handle and have JWTs to check where the request is coming from, so combining that with your answer should be sufficient

Comment: Here's an example of how we solve it in djoser.  https://github.com/sunscrapers/djoser/blob/b648b07dc2da7dab4c00c1c39af3d6ec53f58eb6/djoser/views.py#L51-L58

Comment: Just a quick question, using UUID would require to actually have UUIDs in the database for columns right?

Comment: Yes. You do that on the model level, `UUIDField` with `primary_key=True`.

Answer (score 2):

Let me try to answer this question.

> One can't ensure security just by hiding things

One of my mentor always emphasized on this line whenever I had asked similar questions.

To answer you question, according to me no you don't expose any security flaws by exposing IDs, in fact it's one of the most common way of allowing users to interact with resources over APIs.

You will be surely required to have authentication and authorisation in place to safeguard the resource manipulation by malicious sources. In context of DRF and django you can achieve this by using authentication and permissions.

Hope this answers your question.